# Setup Bootstrap 4.3 on Rails 6 using Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to get Rails 6.0.0 and Bootstrap 4.3 to work with webpack.  I tried a few tutorails like this one [tutorail1](https://medium.com/@guilhermepejon/how-to-install-bootstrap-4-3-in-a-rails-6-app-using-webpack-9eae7a6e2832) and this one [tutorial2](https://gorails.com/episodes/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-webpack-and-rails) but nothing has completely worked.  currently the bootstrap navigation has a black box when hovering over any links, also tooltips and popovers do not work after adding the scripts for them.

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.scss` if you generated a scaffold. You can delete that file.

The scaffolds stylesheet adds a black background when hovering links and some other styles that will conflict with Bootstrap or any other CSS framework.